# Tee with process substitution misunderstanding

Tags: bash, tee, process-substitution

I am trying to write a pretty printer for LDAP entries which only fetches the root LDAP record once and then pipes the output into `tee` that invokes the pretty printer for each section.

For illustration's sake, say my `group_entry` function returns the LDIF of a specific LDAP DN. The details of which aren't important, so let's say it always returns:

```
dn: cn=foo,dc=example,dc=com
cn: foo
owner: uid=foo,dc=example,dc=com
owner: uid=bar,dc=example,dc=com
member: uid=foo,dc=example,dc=com
member: uid=baz,dc=example,dc=com
member: uid=quux,dc=example,dc=com
custom: abc123
```

I can easily extract the owners and members separately with a bit of `grep`'ing and `cut`'ing. I can then pipe those secondary DNs into another LDAP search query to get their real names. For sake of example, let's say I have a `pretty_print` function, that is parametrised on the LDAP attribute name, which does all that I just mentioned and then formats everything nicely with AWK:

```
$ group_entry | pretty_print owner
Owners:
foo    Mr Foo
bar    Dr Bar

$ group_entry | pretty_print member
Members:
foo    Mr Foo
baz    Bazzy McBazFace
quux   The Artist Formerly Known as Quux
```

These work fine individually, but when I try to `tee` them together, nothing happens:

```
$ group_entry | tee >(pretty_print owner) | pretty_print member
Members:
[Sits there waiting for Ctrl+C]
```

Obviously I have some misunderstanding about how this is supposed to work, but it escapes me. What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT** For sake of completeness, here's my full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu -o pipefail

LDAPSEARCH="ldapsearch -xLLL"

group_entry() {
  local group="$1"
  ${LDAPSEARCH} "(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(cn=${group}))"
}

get_attribute() {
  local attr="$1"
  grep "${attr}:" | cut -d" " -f2
}

get_names() {
  # We strip blank lines out of the LDIF entry, then we always have "dn"
  # followed by "cn" records; we strip off the attribute name and
  # concatenate those lines, then sort. So we get a sorted list of:
  # {{distinguished_name}} {{real_name}}
  xargs -n1 -J% ${LDAPSEARCH} -s base -b % cn \
  | grep -v "^$" \
  | cut -d" " -f2- \
  | paste - - \
  | sort
}

pretty_print() {
  local attr="$1"
  local -A pretty=([member]="Members" [owner]="Owners")

  get_attribute "${attr}" \
  | get_names \
  | gawk -F'\t' -v title="${pretty[${attr}]}:" '
    BEGIN { print title }
    { print "-", gensub(/^uid=([^,]+),.*$/, "\\1", "g", $1), "\t", $2 }
  '
}

# FIXME I don't know why tee with process substitution doesn't work here
group_entry "$1" | pretty_print owner
group_entry "$1" | pretty_print member
```

Comment: If you can share the actual code you are trying + your wrong output + your expected output, it will be easy for us to help you better.

Comment: One additional problem is that the call to `pretty_print owner` is inheriting its standard output from the same place as `tee`, which means `pretty_print member` is going to get some additional, unexpected input.

Comment: There's also the issue with the two calls to `pretty_print` running asynchronously, so their output will be likely interleaved if they are writing to the same file.

Comment: (I've added my script now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describe looks very much like a situation that can arise in a C program that forks and exec's another program (as the shell and xargs both certainly do) without properly handling all the open file descriptors.  You can be left in a situation where a process *p1* does not terminate because it's waiting to observe EOF on its standard input, but it never will do because another process *p2* holds an open file descriptor for the write end of the pipe that provides *p1*'s standard input, and *p2* is itself waiting for *p1* to terminate or perform some other action.

Nevertheless, I don't see anything inherently wrong with your pipeline in that regard, and I do not reproduce the hang with this simpler model ...

```
echo "foo" | tee >(cat) | cat
```

... in version 4.2.46 of `bash`.  It may be that there is nevertheless a related bug in your version of `bash` (even if its the same one) or in `xargs`, but that's speculative.  I do not think that your pipeline should hang as you say it does, but I'm not prepared to start pointing fingers.

In any event, even if your pipeline did not hang, it does not have the semantics you want, as @chepner pointed out in comments.  The `pretty_print member` will receive the output of `tee` on its standard input, and that will include *both* the output of `group_entry` and the output of `pretty_print owner`.  You could consider implementing it differently: since tee can multiplex input more than two ways, you may kill two birds with one stone by doing this:

```
group_entry "$1" | tee >(pretty_print owner) >(pretty_print member)
```

But that leaves open the possibility that the output of the two `pretty_print` executions will be intermingled, and also echos the `group_entry` output.  You could conceivably filter out the `group_entry` output, but to avoid the intermingling, you need to ensure that the two `pretty_print` commands run sequentially.  That presents a problem for a `tee`-based approach, because if any of `tee`'s outputs block then the whole pipeline can stall.

One solution would be to redirect the output of one or both `pretty_print` commands to a file.  Alternatively, if it is essential that both outputs go to stdout, then I see no good alternative but to capture the `group_entry` output, and feed it separately to each `pretty_print` job.  You could capture it to a file, but that's unnecessary, and a bit messy.  Consider this instead:

```
entry_lines=$(group_entry "$1")
pretty_print owner  <<<"$entry_lines"
pretty_print member <<<"$entry_lines"
```

That uses command substitution to capture the output of `group_entry` in a shell variable (including newlines), and uses a here string to replay it into each `pretty_print` process.