# Bash Process Substitution usage with tee and while loop

Tags: bash, tee, process-substitution

I want to use **nested** process subtitution with tee in a while loop.

```
while read line; do
  #process line
  echo "--$line"
done < <(cat sample.file | tee >(grep "SPECLINE") | grep "LINESTOPROCESS")
```

Therefore, I need:

- all lines in sample.file that contain "LINETOPROCESS" expression should be passed into the loop, and they will be printed with "--" prefix.
- all lines contain "SPECLINE" needs to be printed in tee's first process substitution (in the grep).

I want to avoid cat-ting the sample.file more than once as it is too large and heavy.

With a simple sample.test file:

```
line1 SPECLINE
line2 LINETOPROCESS
line3 LINETOPROCESS
line4 SPECLINE
line5 I don't need it
line6 also not
line7 also not
line8 SPECLINE
line9 LINETOPROCESS
```

My result:

```
# ./test.sh
#
```

My desired result:

```
# ./test.sh
line1 SPECLINE 
--line2 LINETOPROCESS
--line3 LINETOPROCESS
line4 SPECLINE
line8 SPECLINE
--line9 LINETOPROCESS
```

Or I can also accept this as output:

```
# ./test.sh
--line2 LINETOPROCESS
--line3 LINETOPROCESS
--line9 LINETOPROCESS
line1 SPECLINE 
line4 SPECLINE
line8 SPECLINE
```

**UPDATE1**

greps are for demo only.
I really need those 2 substitutions.

- sample.file is a http file.
- grep "SPECLINE" would be "hxselect -i -s ';' -c 'div.hour'
- grep "LINESTOPROCESS" would be "hxselect -i -s ';' -c 'div.otherclass' | hxpipe

hx programs are not line-oriented. They are reading from stdin and outputting to stdout.

Therefore the tee's first command will select divs with 'hour' class and separate them with ';'. Afterwards, the pipe after tee will select all divs with class 'otherclass' and hxpipe will flatten it for the loop for further processing.

Comment: Having two *asynchronous* `grep` processes, with their output not coordinated with each other, is really not the way to go. If they're line-buffering you won't get garbage, but that's not the default when output is to a non-TTY sink, so you risk a single line containing output from both processes. (Also, it's conceivable that if you had a multi-kb line, you could have content that needed to be split into multiple syscalls even with line-buffered output enabled).

Comment: ...and because the chance of having garbage happen when both processes in the substitution are writing simultaneously depends on the amount of output, line lengths, and runtime details like whether syscalls are ever interrupted, it's not something you can just test for, say "no, it doesn't ever happen", and then not worry about going forward.

Comment: Also, if output is not line-oriented, that makes merging together the output of two separate runs in an uncertain and uncontrolled order *even more* dangerous.

Comment: Given the update: I think you're trying to optimize the wrong thing. Reading the file from disk twice is unlikely to be as important as the fact that you're parsing it twice with `hxselect`. I'd be inclined to look at running `hxselect` once selecting both `div.hour` *and* `div.otherclass`, and then split the output from that. (Unless most of the file matches one or the other, in which case you're just doomed.)

Comment: Alternately: write your script/program in language that can actually process the file and do what you want directly, rather than having to splice together different tools each of which does only part of what you want.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, thanks! Actually, latest hxselect is broken as it is not handling the comma operator. So basically it can not filter for multiple queries. When it will be fixed, I can easily solve the above problem. For now, I will use a temp file (created by mktemp) and trash it after the hx functions are finished.

Answer (score 4):

I would use no process substitution at all.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line = *SPECLINE* ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  elif [[ $line = *LINETOPROCESS* ]]; then
    printf '--%s\n' "$line"
  fi
done < sample.txt
```

You are already paying the cost of reading an input stream line-by-line in `bash`; no reason to add the overhead of two separate `grep` processes to it.

A single `awk` process would be even better, as it is more efficient than `bash`'s read-one-character-at-a-time approach to reading lines of text.

```
awk '/SPECLINE/ {print} /LINETOPROCESS/ {print "--"$0}' sample.txt
```

(which is *too* simple if a single line could match both `SPECLINE` and `LINETOPROCESS`, but I leave that as an exercise to the reader to fix.)

Answer (score 0):

The following just loops through the entire file and just prints the matching lines. All other lines are ignored.

```
while read line; do
    case "$line" in
        *SPECLINE*) echo "$line" ;;
        *LINETOPROCESS*) echo "--$line" ;;
    esac
done < sample.file
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want the `tee`, you can make 2 changes.
Your testcode greps LINE**S**TOPROCESS, the input is LINETO..
The output process substition gives problems like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42766913/3220113 explained. You can do this differently.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  #process line
  echo "--$line"
done < x2 |
tee >(grep "SPECLINE") >(grep "LINETOPROCESS") >/dev/null
```

I don't know `hxselect`, but it seems to operate on a complete well-formed XML document, so avoid the `grep`.